# From FBV to CBV with multiple forms

Tags: django, django-views

So I deal with multiple forms in my view, which as far as I get disallow the use of a FormView.

But is there a way to convert it to a Formview or any other CBV? And how would I approach this.

My view:

```
def new_invoice(request):
    InvoiceItemFormset = inlineformset_factory(Invoice, InvoiceItem, fields=('service',
                                                                             'unit_price',
                                                                             'quantity',
                                                                             'vat_rule',
                                                                             'unit'))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        invoice_form = NewInvoiceForm(request.POST)
        if invoice_form.is_valid():
            invoice = invoice_form.save(commit=False)
            invoice.user = request.user
            invoice.save()
            formset = InvoiceItemFormset(request.POST, instance=invoice)
            if formset.is_valid():
                formset.save()
                return redirect('dashboard:dashboard')
    else:
        formset = InvoiceItemFormset()
        invoice_form = NewInvoiceForm()

    context = {
        'invoice_form': invoice_form,
        'formset': formset,
        'invoice': Invoice,
        'time': date
    }
    return render(request, 'dashboard/new-invoice.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert your FBV into a CBV using django's `TemplateView`.

**views.py**

```py
django.views.generic import TemplateView

class NewInvoiceView(TemplateView):

    template_name = 'dashboard/new-invoice.html'

    def get(request, *args, **kwargs):
        InvoiceItemFormset = inlineformset_factory(Invoice, InvoiceItem, fields=('service','unit_price','quantity','vat_rule','unit'))
        formset = InvoiceItemFormset()
        invoice_form = NewInvoiceForm()
        context = {
            'invoice_form': invoice_form,
            'formset': formset,
            'invoice': Invoice,
            'time': date}
        return render(request, self.template_name, context)

    def post(request, *args, **kwargs):
        invoice_form = NewInvoiceForm(request.POST)
        if invoice_form.is_valid():
            invoice = invoice_form.save(commit=False)
            invoice.user = request.user
            invoice.save()
            formset = InvoiceItemFormset(request.POST, instance=invoice)
            if formset.is_valid():
                formset.save()
                return redirect('dashboard:dashboard')
       
        formset = InvoiceItemFormset(request.POST)
        context = {
            'invoice_form': invoice_form,
            'formset': formset,
            'invoice': Invoice,
            'time': date}

        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

Make sure you import the class into your `urls.py` like so `NewInvoiceView.as_view()`

*Note: I've assumed `date` is a global variable defined outside of this class*